# This is a data visualisation and data manipulation question for Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

Firstly, I'm sorry if this is a silly question but I would appreciate any guidance.

I have pulled out some financial data in Microsoft Excel:

Column A: Company Names
Column B: GIC Sector Names
Column C: 5 day share price change (%) since its last reported EPS. So if Company A reported on 23/03/2021, I have taken the post 5 day share price change.
Column D: EPS surprise (can be positive or negative)
Column E: 1 Year EPS upgrade or downgrade - in % terms

What I want to show is Shares Prices have not reacted even if the company has reported a positive EPS surprise. The post 5 days share price reaction has been muted.

I am not sure how to go about bringing this data alive... I thought a scatter plot would be useful, but it looks extremely cluttered. X-axis: EPS surprise vs Y-axis: 5-Day share price change. At the moment, I have over 100 companies, some of them are in the communications sector (10 companies), health care (7 Companies), Financials etc.

Options:

1. Break is down by sector: One Scatter Plot for Communications Sector, One for Financials, one for healthcare etc.
2. Ideally I want to put it all on one chart - Maybe I could do manipulate the Sector Names and 5 day price change (%), and the EPS surprise so it all gets captured on 1 data point? Thereby, if i apply a scatter plot - I only have 10 sector names, instead of 100 names. But, I dont know how I should go about doing this?

Any views or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your excel as a table and show an example of what you need...

Comment: Just added to the main question i posted. Not the best chart but x-axis are 5 day share price change, and y-axis are EPS surprise.